# long variable with leading zero output

Tags: java

I am not able to understand the why such output when long variable with **leading zero**.

```
public class Test{
        public static void main(String[] args) {
             long var1=00123l;
             long var2=123l;
             System.out.println("Variable 1--->"+var1);
             System.out.println("Variable 2--->"+var2);
             System.out.println(var1==var2);
        }
    }
```

**output:**

```
Variable 1--->83
Variable 2--->123
false
```

Comment: leading zeros means octal notation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The leading zero turns `00123l` into an [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) literal, and 123<sub>8</sub>=83<sub>10</sub>.

From the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1):

> An octal numeral consists of an ASCII digit 0 followed by one or more of the ASCII digits 0 through 7 interspersed with underscores, and can represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.

When you print the value, it gets printed in base-10, so you see `83`.

Comment: Thanks, your given specification helpful+1. I have added a comment to @CodeMan. does any solution other than format output?

Comment: @Bhumika: To be honest, I don't fully understand the problem you're trying to solve. Where are those literals coming from? What do you need to do with them?

Comment: Ok, As sort explain then I want to treat a a long type variable as long only even lead zero. so there is no any ways. A case where a variable is used in calculation and preview also. the calculation become wrong due to leading zero and if I remove leading zero the preview wrong. You know that we can solve it by logic but a stander way to do it. so before I accept a answer I want to know possible solution if exist.

Comment: @Bhumika: If the number originates from outside your code, you simply read it as a string and then use `Integer.valueOf(s, 10)`. That'll treat it as base-10 regardless of any leading zeroes.

Answer (score 7):

when a literal is prefixed with 0; java treats it as a octal number. When you print that same number, by default it prints in base(10) format. Hence `00123l` is printed as `83`.

Comment: Ok. thanks. but Do you know a way which stop conversion in base(10) format? correct me if no any way. because some cases I have such values. so I have to manually remove those leading zero. sometime leading zero required to show in preview also. so how can I handle such case?

Comment: you can print the octal number as it is using the following syntax

`int num = 032;`

`System.out.printf("%04o", num);`

Note: Please be careful if u work with the mixture of Base(8) and Base(10) number. Make sure that your other calculations don't crib.

Answer (score 4):

When you add a leading zero to a value, it is interpreted as an octal value.

Integers can not store any leading zeros. When you need those, store the number as a String.

Answer (score 2):

When you write an integer literal with leading zeroes, it is interpreted as an [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) number. `00123` in octal is `83` in decimal.

Answer (score 0):

`00123` or `0123` or `0123l` all are same for Java. You can test. They are octal numbers. If you convert them, you will find `(1X8^2)+(1X8^1)(1X8^0)=64+16+3=83`. If you want you can store them as String.